# Java TCP latency

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, latency

I am developing an Android application communicating with a TCP Java-server over a WLAN connection. The Android application is a game with sprites being moved around the screen. Whenever a sprite moves, the AndroidClient sends its coordinates to the Java-server, wich then sends the data to the other clients (maximum 4 clients). The server handles each client on a separate thread, data updates are sent about every 20 ms., and each packet consists of about 1-10 bytes. I am on a 70 Mbit network (with about 15 Mbit effective on my Wireless).

I am having problems with an unstable connection, and experiencing latency at about 50-500 ms. every 10th-30th packet. I have set the tcpNoDelay to true, wich stopped the consistent 200ms latency, although it still lags a lot. As I am quite new to both Android and networking I don't know whether this is to be expected or not. I am also wondering if UDP could be suitable for my program, as I am interested in sending updates fast rather than every packet arriving correctly.

I would appreciate any guidance as to how to avoid/work around this latency problem. General tips on how to implement such a client-server architecture would also be applauded.

Comment: UDP definitely sounds like a better option.

Comment: for a game, you probably want to add some prediction (you've probably seen the effect of a misprediction on some games).

Comment: Capture network activity with wireshark or tcpdump and post it here.

Comment: It sounds like your protocol just wasn't designed to work over TCP with low latency. Can you explain how it works? For example, how does it ensure ACK piggybacking? The fact that setting tcpNoDelay to true helped, when it should have hurt, is a strong indication that your protocol was never designed for low latency over TCP. My guesses would be: 1) Your write code is probably terrible and pushes partial application-level messages to the transport layer. 2) Your protocol is probably terrible and doesn't have application-level acknowledgements where they're needed for latency reduction.

Answer (score 2):

On a wireless LAN you'll occasionally see dropped packets, which results in a packet retransmission after a delay. If you want to control the delay before retransmission you're almost certainly going to have to use UDP.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want to use UDP. For a game you don't care if the position of a sprite is incorrect for a short time. So UDP is ideal in this case.

Also, if you have any control over the server code, I would not use separate threads for clients. Threads are useful if you need to make calls to libraries that you don't have control over and that can block (such as because they touch a file or try to perform additional network communication). But they are expensive. They consume a lot of resources and as such they actually make things *slower* than they could be.

So for a network game server where latency and performance are absolutely critical, I would just use one thread to process a queue of commands that have a state and then make sure that you never perform an operation that blocks. So each command is processed in order, it's state is evaluated and updated (like a laser blast intersected with another object). If the command requires blocking (like reading from a file) then you need to perform a non-blocking read and set the state of that command accordingly so that your command processor never blocks. The key is that the command processor can never never ever block. It would just run in a loop but you would have to call Thread.sleep(x) in an appropriate way so as not to waste CPU.

As for the client side, when a client submits a command (like they fired a laser or some such), the client would generate a response object and insert it into a Map with a sequence id as the key. Then it would send the request with the sequence id and when the server responds with the that id, you just lookup the response object in the Map and decode the response into that object. Meaning this allows you to perform concurrent operations.